# C# Textbox on Textmode number not triggering on empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am implementing a grid view and putting a textbox in the Headers to be able to filter the data for each column. I have the following code for the ontextchanged trigger for every textbox.

```
protected void Filter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ColumnName = ((TextBox)sender).Attributes["EventArg"];
        string FilterValue = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterValue))
        {
            EntityDataSource1.Where = "";
        }
        else
        {
            int dummy;
            if (int.TryParse(FilterValue, out dummy))
            {
                EntityDataSource1.Where = "it." + ColumnName + " = " + FilterValue;
            }else
            {
                EntityDataSource1.Where = "it." + ColumnName + " Like '%" + FilterValue + "%'";
            }
        }
    }
```

The aspx is as follows

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCaseNr" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnTextChanged="Filter_TextChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
```

Everything works so far except that to prevent text being written at textboxes expecting integers i set the `textmode=number`. And it is not being triggered when the textbox is emptied to remove the filter.

I hope my problem is clear. Any solutions are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: do not use TextMode="number" / if you want to parse int, you need a RegularExpressionValidator

Comment: I have a grid view with 14 columns and each with a textbox. I would have to put 14 regularExpresionValidators. It doesnt look to clean to me. Is this normal practice?

Comment: Already figured that my problem was somewhere else. I realized that the value of the textbox was dissapearing after postback. And then of course there is no trigger on an empty textbox. I already saw answers to this new problem. Is there a way to close this question?